# How to query Firebase database object when criteria property is nested?

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have the following structure in Firebase database:

```
root
 - Users
 - Posts
   - -K_54s1smPPh6qN4znuT
     - key1: val
     - key2: val
     - User:
       - -K_54sSomeKeyFromUsersObject: "John Doe"
...
```

But I can't find any example in documentation how can I fetch all `Posts` by `UserKey` when I have structure like this.

I need help on how to make a query to compare nested data like this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to approach this is to save the reference to the posts on the user. Like this:

```
root
 - Users
   - [UserID]
      - UserPosts
        -K_54s1smPPh6qN4znuT
 - Posts
   - -K_54s1smPPh6qN4znuT
     - key1: val
     - key2: val
     - User:
       - -K_54sSomeKeyFromUsersObject: "John Doe"
...
```

So when you want to retrieve all posts by an user, you just look at the references on the user profile

Comment: So when I got all keys from user object this means that I need to make another request to get all posts from Posts right?

Comment: Yes, but you can limit the number of posts. Getting 10 references to posts and using a pagenation if the user wants more, is a good solution

Comment: Ok, just one last subquestion... in firebase I can make a query where I can pass list of key that I want to get back... like in SQL WHERE Posts.ID in (k1, k2, k3...)?

Comment: I think there are several good examples on these two videos. I think the second video answers your question, but watch both since they are very easy to follow:
#1: 
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sKFLI5FOOHs

and
#2:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Idu9EJPSxiY

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest an alternative

```
users
  uid_0
    name: "Frank"
  uid_1
    name: "Biff"

posts
  post_0
    msg: "some post"
    user_id: "uid_0"
  post_1
    msg: "Another post"
    user_id: "uid_1"
```

then a simple query will return all of uid_0's posts

```
let postsRef = root.child("posts")

postsRef.queryOrdered(byChild: "user_id").queryEqual(toValue: "uid_0")
        .observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { snapshot in
    print(snapshot)  //prints all of uid_0's posts
})
```

This avoids the need to gather up the post id's and then try to perform a SQL-like query WHERE Posts.ID in (k1, k2, k3...) as Firebase doesn't offer a query like that directly.

In response to a follow up comment about how to handle when a single post has multiple users...

```
posts
  post_0
    msg: "some post"
    users:
      uid_0: true
      uid_1: true
  post_1
    msg: "Another post"
    users:
      uid_1: true
      uid_2: true
```

The code to get the nodes that contain uid_1: true is similar and called a [deep query](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2015/09/introducing-multi-location-updates-and_86.html) or deep paths. That's an older post but will give you really good information.

```
let postsRef = root.child("posts")

postsRef.queryOrdered(byChild: "users/uid_1").queryEqual(toValue: true)
        .observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { snapshot in
    print(snapshot)  //prints all of uid_0's posts
})
```

Comment: Hi, thanks but how can I apply this design when Posts can have multiple users on it. One post must have a list of users in it. That is why I created Users child it is a list.

Comment: @1110  I assume you mean that Posts can have multiple users watching the post? If so, I updated my answer to handle that. There's nothing wrong with the accepted answer, I just wanted to provide an alternative.

Comment: I like more this approach but it simply doesn't work. Snapshot is always null.

Comment: Based on second design you added (after comment) how to write a query to return all posts for 'uid_1'?

Comment: This return me null: ref.child("posts").child("users").queryOrdered(byChild: "-KXFrbzxUwaBGjtmjfGr")
            .observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { snapshot in
                print(snapshot)
            })

Comment: @1110 That's not how a query would work. If you know the specific path then you can observe that path directly and you don't need a query, but if you do that, it will only return that one node. In this case however, you want to return *all* nodes that have a child user_id: uid_0 (or in my second example where uid_0: true) so you need to query for uid_0 as in my example. The code in my example is tested and works based on the Firebase structure also posted in the answer.

Comment: Can you please add a code for seconds example structure. I bang my head whole day can't write a query to get a list of user posts. When structure is Object...Users...u1,u1...

Comment: @1110 For sure! Done!

Comment: Tnx :-) I thought that this design is bad and almost changed how my data are stored. I am still new with nosql and firebase, tnx once again.